# How to move an Ubuntu VM from Windows host to Ubuntu host?

Tags: virtualization

I am running Ubuntu (12.04) virtual machine (on VirtualBox). My host machine is Windows 7, however. I need to move (copy ?) my Ubuntu VM in its current state  into an other computer  where the host machine is Ubuntu. Is there a solution to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Import/Export Appliance options in the File menu of VirtualBox. (Export Appliance on your Windows system will create an OVA file of your VM, which you can then import on your Ubuntu system.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it in few hours and will accept your answer if it works. Regards